# Why work function is not identical to first ionization energy?

Tags: photoelectric-effect, ionization-energy

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization_energy):

> The ionization energy (IE) is qualitatively defined as the amount of
>   energy required to remove the most loosely bound electron of an
>   isolated gaseous atom to form a cation.

and:

> Work function is the energy required to strip an electron from a solid
>   to just outside its surface.

Then why the first ionization energy is not identical to the work function? (there is roughly a factor of 1.5 between the two quantities)

[image]([source](http://www.materialsscience.pwr.wroc.pl/bi/vol24no4/articles/IMIM_12.pdf))

Comment: Duplicate? http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/205310/whats-the-difference-between-the-work-function-and-ionisation-energy

Comment: @Farcher the answer in the question you link to does not answer the question actually, only repeats definitions.

Answer (score 1):

For condensed matter the important value is the Fermi energy; this depends upon the material structure, and is a many body problem.

Comment: This is the right answer but perhaps you could explain to the OP what is the Fermi sea…